# gofundme widget is not appearing on page

Tags: widget

Gofundme gave me the following widget code to add to my webpage, however it doesn't appear on my page.  I think that it might have something to do with the embed tag as my design software states that "In HTML 4.01 Transitional the tag  is not permitted."  Could that be the problem?

Here's the code they sent me:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="258" height="338" title="Click Here to donate!" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="movie" value="/Widgetflex.swf"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="flashvars" value="page=drum-lessons-for-indigent-students&template=6"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><embed allowScriptAccess="always" src="/Widgetflex.swf" quality="high" flashVars="page=drum-lessons-for-indigent-students&template=6" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="258" height="338"></embed></object>
```

Comment: You haven't even mentioned what your design software is, so there's not much anyone can do to help.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Expression Web 4.

Answer (score 1):

Kokesh is right, there are some issues with flash in some instances but the real issue with the gofundme widget has to do with how it's written for you to copy and paste. It's looking for a local file.

This tutorial should help with getting it to work using a workaround.
http://manicpixieropedoll.blogspot.com/p/gofundme-n.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a Flash object. Flash is on it's way out and already blocked in Chrome. Do they provide some more civilized solution? I actually found your question as this happened just now to my wife.. I will look for solutions, but unless GoFundMe provides other widget, I'm not sure what to do.